# Spring MVC & JSR 303 validation leads to error 400

Tags: spring-mvc, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

OK. I have a Spring MVC controller method as below:

```
public String getInformationByGID(@ModelAttribute("geoInfoParam") @Valid GeoInfoParam geoInfoParam, Model model ,BindingResult result)
```

GeoInfoParam class defines has a number of inputs with @NotNull, @Size annotated validations, which I expect to be executed when I submit form (as I have  @Valid with ModelAttribute). But what happened, When I click submit, page showed me 400 error and did not show anyother information in log.

Answer (score 16):

I debugged the execution flow and found that org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java ( which is part HandlerAdapter execution).handleBindException is called when there is no BindingResult followed by ModelAttribute and this method sets response with 400 code.
The lesson I learned is If you have a form(ModelAttribute) annotated with @Valid, make sure it is followed by BindingResult immediately.
So I have changed my controller method signature as below:

```
public String getInformationByGID(@ModelAttribute("geoInfoParam") @Valid GeoInfoParam geoInfoParam, BindingResult result, Model model)
```

Silly Me. Now everthing is fine. Hope this helps someone.

NB: I use Spring MVC 3.2.8 and Hibernate validator 4.2.0 final

Comment: Thank you for this! You have saved me from jumping out from a bridge! LOL!
But now, I wonder how to validate two or more `ModelAtributes` at once (I've got the case where I need to persist two Entities).

Comment: I ran into this gotcha today.  The documentation confirms it.  See, for example,  https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.14.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-methods:

```The Errors or BindingResult parameters have to follow the model object that is being bound immediately as the method signature might have more than one model object and Spring will create a separate BindingResult instance for each of them...```